# SSL Installed but no lock only on index.html

Tags: html, ssl

I know this will be marked as a duplicate but I am unable to find a solution.

So I've purchased an SSL cert from COMODO and on every single page of my website, there is a normal nice looking green lock except for my newly created index.html. The homepage used to be index.php but was changed to index.html and now there is no lock on the homepage.

Any ideas why & how to fix this?

Edit:
On my index.html it successfully has it all encrypted and all and it sits at https:// but the only thing missing is the lock.

Comment: This is not related to programming. You should ask it on Server Fault. Beside that you should tell what browser you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check all URLs of 
CSS, Javascripts , Images and another resources must be loaded with

```
https://
```

If single 1px image is load from `http` it will not work.

Comment: Thank you sir, you really helped!